# Laravel Multi Select with Select2 Ajax

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, jquery-select2

I implemented a `Many To Many` relation between `Posts` and `Tags`. I am using `Select2 Ajax` for `Multi Select` and html is rendered by the `Spatie/HTML` package.

In the create form, I can select the tags and while i same the database table updates successfully. I can also show the tags.

I am facing an issue in the edit form. I am using the same create form for the edit and though the Tags has been attached earlier i can not see those as selected. What is the solution of this. Some of the codes are mentioned below.

Form

`{{ html()->multiselect('tags_list', '', $posts->tags->pluck('id')->toArray())->class('form-control select2-tags')) }}`

Model:

`public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but is there any better solution? may be via Model?

`{{ html()->multiselect('tags_list', $posts->tags->pluck('name', 'id'), $posts->tags->pluck('id')->toArray())->class('form-control select2-tags')) }}`